# DropDownlist search/Autocompletion

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp-classic, autocomplete

Is there a way to return items containing at least one word from the text in the search box of a dropdownlist.

There is plenty of ajax tutorials, but they all return items containing the whole searched text.

Till now I'm using [JQUERY Autocompete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

I need to change the RegEx to be able to achieve what I want :

```
// Initialize ajax autocomplete:
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
    lookup: countriesArray,
    lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
        return re.test(suggestion.value);
    },
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    onHint: function (hint) {
        $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
    },
    onInvalidateSelection: function() {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Comment: @GSDa Could you show your code to provide you with help? If we do not know what did you do or at least try to do, how anyone can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your RegExp to search for the whole word anywhere within the suggestion, like this:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase) + '\\b', 'gi');
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to search for just part of the word, you could change to indexOf, like this:

```
lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
    return re.test(suggestion.value.indexOf(queryLowerCase) != -1);
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I discovered Fuzzy libs. I'm using now FuzzySet.js it's more efficient in search.